# Background hover colour and overflowing navigation element z-index issue

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index, uinavigationitem

Can anyone help me with this problem I have.  Quite hard to summarise into a single sentance.

Anyhow.

I have an accordion, made up of list items.  Each list item has an anchor link to expand the item.  The anchor link is positioned absolutely so that it is a the bottom centre of the list item and overflowing by 10px into the next list item.  When you hover over a list item a background colour is applied.

The problem is this.

When you roll over a list item, the background colour appears over the top of the previous list items anchor link.

I've put the html/css on jsfiddle

```
<ul class="entries">
<li>
  <article class="expand-parent">
      <a href="#" class="show-more ir expand-link"><span>Show more</span></a>
      <header>
          <time datetime="">Date</time>
          <hgroup>
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <h6>Sub heading</h6>
          </hgroup>
      </header>
      <div class="item expand-target">
          <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </article>
</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magicspon/GzB44/

Has anyone got any suggestions how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the z-index of the background image element itself too.

```
ul.entries li:hover {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url("http://labs.gumproductions.co.uk/jsfiddle/ui/news-bg.png");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
z-index:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GzB44/2/

Comment: That's super... Many thanks.  I've just removed z-index: 1 from the li entirely.  Ace